# ordered n-tuples of elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $a,b$ be elements of some sets. I define:
$$\langle a,b\rangle:=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$$

Inductively, for every $n$ I define:
$$\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1}\rangle:=\langle \langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle,x_{n+1}\rangle$$

Then I apply the definition to the case $n=2$, and what I get is:

$$\langle a,b,c\rangle=\{\{\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}\},\{\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\},c\} \}$$

which is totally confusing me. Could you please clarify that?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA got it, so (a,b)=(c,d) if and only if a=c and b=d. But what if I want to consider triples, 4-tuples, ..., n-tuples, how can I write them in a simple way as for n=2?

Comment: For triple $((a,b), c)=((d,e),f)$ iff $(a,b)=(d,e)$ and $c=f$. The first one, in turn, iff $a=d$ and $b=e$. In conclusion: iff $a=d$ and $b=e$ and $c=f$. And this is all we want from an ordered triple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind the definition of *pair* it is that we must have a set with two elements but we must be able to characterize them in some way.

The trick is: the first element of the pair has one element while the second element has two. Thus, we cannot mix them up.

In the definition of ordered *triple*, we have again a pair: the first element is in turn a pair while the second element is a set that has two elements.

Thus, for triples $((a,b),c)$ and $((d,e),f)$, they are equl iff $(a,b)=(d,e)$ and $c=f$.

For the first one, being a pair, we have that: $a=d$ and $b=e$.

In conclusion, the two triples are equal iff:

> $a=d$ and $b=e$ and $c=f$,

and this is all we want from an ordered triple.

Answer (score 3):

Too much for a comment.

There is an alternative way of defining tuples that is in my view less confusing.

For $n\geq3$ you can define tuple $\langle x_1,\dots, x_n\rangle$ to be a function $f$ on set $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with $f(i)=x_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

Then formally $$\langle x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle:=\{\langle i,x_i\rangle\mid i\in\{1,\dots,n\}\}$$

Here only the ordered pairs $\langle i,x_i\rangle$ on RHS need a further definition, and for this you can fall back on $\langle i,x_i\rangle=\{\{i\},\{i,x_i\}\}$.